# Sequelize Top level where with eagerly loaded models creates sub query

Tags: subquery, sequelize.js, eager-loading

I'm running an into issue where Sequelize creates a subquery of the primary model and then joins the includes with that subquery instead of directly with the primary model table. The query conditions for the include(s) ends up inside the subquery's WHERE clause which makes it invalid. I have shortened names down trying to keep this compact hopefully without losing any relevant info.

Environment:
Nodejs: 6.11.3
Sequelize: 3.23.6 => Updated to 4.38.1 and problem persists
MySql: 5.7.23

Code snip models:

```
I.model:
   models.I.hasMany(models.II);
   models.I.belongsTo(models.CJ);
   models.I.belongsTo(models.CJS);
II.model:
   models.II.belongsTo(models.I);
CJ.model:
   models.CJ.hasMany(models.I);
   models.CJ.hasMany(models.CJS);
CJS.model:
    models.CJS.hasMany(models.I);
```

Code snip query definition:

```
let where = { cId: '2',
iAmt: { '$gt': 0 },
'$or': 
 [ { '$CJ.a1$': {$like: '%246%'}} },
   { '$CJ.a2$': {$like: '%246%'} },
   { '$I.cPN$': {$like: '%246%'} } 
 ] };

 let query = {
   where: where,
   order: orderBy,
   distinct: true,
   offset: offset,
   limit: limit,
   include: [
   {
    model: CJ, 
    as: 'CJ',
    required: false
  }, {
    model: CJS, 
    as: 'CJS',
    required: false
  }, {
    model: II,
    as: 'IIs',
    required: false
  }
  ]
  };

  I.findAll(query)
```

Produces SQL like the following:

```
SELECT `I`.*, `CJ`.`_id` AS `CJ._id`, `CJS`.`_id` AS `CJS._id`, `IIs`.`_id` AS `IIs._id`
FROM (SELECT `I`.`_id`, `I`.`CJId`, `I`.`CJSId`, `I`.`CId` 
  FROM `Is` AS `I` 
 WHERE `I`.`CId` = '2' AND 
       `I`.`iA` > 0 AND 
     (`CJ`.`a1` LIKE '%246%' OR 
      `CJ`.`a2` LIKE '%246%' OR 
      `I`.`cPN` LIKE '%246%'
     ) 
     ORDER BY `I`.`iNum` DESC LIMIT 0, 10) AS `I` 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN `CJs` AS `CJ` ON `I`.`CJId` = `CJ`.`_id` 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN `CJSs` AS `CJS` ON `I`.`CJSId` = `CJS`.`_id` 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN `IIs` AS `IIs` ON `I`.`_id` = `IIs`.`IId` 
     ORDER BY `I`.`iNum` DESC;
```

I was expecting something like this:

```
SELECT `I`.*, `CJ`.`_id` AS `CJ._id`, `CJS`.`_id` AS `CJS._id`, `IIs`.`_id` AS `IIs._id`
  FROM `Is` AS `I` 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN `CJs` AS `CJ` ON `I`.`CJId` = `CJ`.`_id` 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN `CJSs` AS `CJS` ON `I`.`CJSId` = `CJS`.`_id` 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN `IIs` AS `IIs` ON `I`.`_id` = `IIs`.`IId` 

WHERE `I`.`CId` = '2' AND 
       `I`.`iA` > 0 AND 
     (`CJ`.`a1` LIKE '%246%' OR 
      `CJ`.`a2` LIKE '%246%' OR 
      `I`.`cPN` LIKE '%246%'
) 
ORDER BY `I`.`iNum` DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

If I remove the **II** model from the include it does work and moves the the WHERE to the top level. I admit the structure of the query is not straight forward here, with **I** being a child of **CJ** and **CJS**, which in turn is a child of **CJ**. And then **II** a child of **I**. What am I missing here?

Bueller's or anyone's 2 cent welcome!

Answer (score 7):

what happened here is because you also using `order` and `limit` together with eager loading association [see the issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2004)

to make it work, there is a little hacky solution, you need to add `subQuery: false` together to your root model query

```
let query = {
   where: where,
   order: orderBy,
   distinct: true,
   offset: offset,
   limit: limit,
   subQuery: false,
   include: [...]
};
```